# convert range of numeric variable maintaining ratio

Tags: r, range, numeric, wrangle

how do I change the range of a numeric variable? Now it’s 100.000-1.000000, which is way too big. It's personIDs of survey respondents. They number of observations is actually only 926.

If I don't change this, my plot looks wrongs, since it looks like I have up to 1 million observations.

Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `seq(length(your_variable))` ?

Comment: Or convert the ID number to a factor?

Comment: tried both, and they don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to create new id's.

```
library(dplyr)

original_id <- sample(100000:1000000,size = 5)

data.frame(original_id) %>% 
  mutate(new_id = row_number())

 original_id new_id
1      518768      1
2      367757      2
3      862740      3
4      328574      4
5      540609      5
```